# PostgreSQL-10: query JSONB property with multiple types

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-10

Assume a table `json_table` with a column `data (jsonb)`. A sample value would be

```json
{"a": [{"b":{"c": "xxx", "d": 1}},{"b":{"c": "xxx", "d": 2}}]}
```

I used to run SQL queries like the following:

```sql
SELECT data
FROM json_table j
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM jsonb_array_elements(j.data#>'{a}') dt 
                  WHERE (dt#>>'{b,d}')::integer IN (2, 4, 6, 9)
                 );
```

The problem is that now property `d` needs to have a dual type, either integer or string. This means that the aforementioned query will crash with

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "d-string-value"`

I would like to avoid the obvious solution of creating two properties `d_id` and `d_name`.

So, is there any way to query the dual type JSONB property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about casting to text instead?

```
WHERE (dt#>>'{b,d}')::text IN ('2', '4', '6', '9')
```

Comment: Yes, of course this works! So clumsy of me. This is actually the first thing I tried before posting the question. It failed for reasons irrelevant to this problem that I missed.